# Unable to add site to Google Push despite being owner in webmaster tools

Tags: google-api, push, google-search-console

I am currently getting "You do not have access to the following domain:" error in Google developer console when attempting to use the "Configure webhook notifications" button for Google API push notifications despite the fact that the very same site / domain is listed as mine in Webmaster Tools and I have access to all of the services there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you also registered "**https**://yourdomain.com" in google webmaster tools, because the webhooks require https.

The very same thing is happening to me since about one week. I can add all kinds of domains to the push notification list, even "www.chatgrape.com" but not "chatgrape.com".

I described the problem in the Google Product Forums in detail but nobody was able to help me yet: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/apps/general-discussion/Numad1TlCJ8

Comment: This works for Google App Engine endpoints as well - and is also necessary for using Google's new PubSub service.  +100 if I could give it for this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes I actually found that it would only work if I had the https version of the URL registered in Webmaster tools. However, the reason that I can use an https version is that there are some SSL services included with a free CloudFlare account. This does not include using a signed certificate installed on your server. To use Google push, you need to have a certificate installed and it cannot be self signed.

Comment: Awesome, awesome answer - just what I was looking for. They really should indicate that `https://` is required instead of showing `www.example.com` as the example placeholder :/